# prevent typing non ascii characters in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, textbox, ascii

Since I think people have encounter it lots of time before I did and there may be some standart solution.. Can anybody give any hint direction how to prevent a user from typing non ascii characters in a textbox.

Comment: Do you need to do this client-side? Why not do it server-side? That way you can still strip out characters you don't want even if the user has JavaScript turned off. Also, preventing users from entering non-ASCII characters seems a bit naïve, a bit passé ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "non-ASCII"? Unicode characters? Or simply characters beyond the 0-127 range?

Answer (score 2):

I personally find tinkering with standard modes of interaction a bit annoying, but if you must filter keyboard input, you can do it by intercepting key press events and canceling the ones that you don't want:

```
var allowed = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/; // etc.

window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("test");

    input.onkeypress = function () {
        // Cross-browser
        var evt = arguments[0] || event;
        var char = String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode);

        // Is the key allowed?
        if (!allowed.test(char)) {
            // Cancel the original event
            evt.cancelBubble = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

And it's more concise and prettier with jQuery:

```
var allowed = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/; // etc.

$(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("test");

    $("#input").keypress(function (e) {
        // Is the key allowed?
        if (!allowed.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
            // Cancel the original event
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your regex should be "var allowed = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/;"

Comment: @Vlad: Thanks for noticing! Fixed.

Comment: There is one problem with this, it doesn't allow the user to backspace/delete to correct what he entered in the field nor does it allow the user to use the arrow keys to move around the field. Is there a more elegant way to handle this than just adding this to the beginning of the function:     
    if (e.keyCode == 8) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 38) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 39) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 40) return;

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a concise ASP.NET solution, you can use the RegularExpressionValidator control to restrict the contents of an ASP.NET TextBox. You don't have to write any server or client side code other than the page tag definition and the regular expression used for validation. Validation will get checked at both sides for you.

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtItem" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="SomeFieldValidator" runat="server" 
  CssClass="SomeClass" ControlToValidate="txtItem" 
  ErrorMessage="This field only accepts ASCII input." Display="Dynamic"
  ValidationExpression="^[A-Za-z0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

In this snippet, **txtItem** is the TextBox that needs validation. the **SomeFieldValidator** control is linked using the *ControlToValidate* attribute to the **txtItem** control. The *ValidationExpression* attribute is the regular expression that is used to enforce the contents of the TextBox. Per the documentation, this expression needs to be written to be compatible with both JScript and .NET Regex regular expressions. Also, I've only set the regular expression here to alpha-numeric characters. You might want to consider using something like **^[\w\s]*$** instead- if you are actually interested in printable characters instead of just ASCII.

A side benefit to using this technique is that you can also insert these validators into .aspx pages of updatable applications, without requiring anything other than an App Pool restart.

Also handy is the **RequiredFieldValidator** control. You can link these with **TextBox** controls that also have a **RegularExpressionValidator** attached. These handle the case of requiring input in a **TextBox**.

Here are some reference links.

[RegularExpressionValidator Control at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx)

[RequiredFieldValidator Control at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h.aspx)

[Character Classes at MSDN (for Regular Expressions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx)

[JavaScript RegExp Object Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)