# How to restrict '♥♣' characters in text box

Tags: mysql, html, ruby-on-rails

How can i restrict '♥♣' like characters from saving into database. If these characters appear in name text field, a error message should be thrown.
I am using ruby on rails.

Thanks,
Anubhaw

Comment: Do you want to prevent certain characters (blacklist), or prevent everything but a certain set of characters (whitelist)?

Comment: Whitelisting is better (if possible) since then you're not going to get surprised by things you didn't think about. (Well, you're less likely to be surprised by them…)

Comment: Actually i want restrict name like '♥♣name♣♥' this. Value for following ♣♥ in database is â™¥â™£. So how do i restrict following and look alike.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Man, I hate when I can't write my lastname (with an ä) into a textbox for some godforsaken reason. Protect yourself from SQL injection using parameterized queries instead.

Comment: It looks like your issue is actually a different one: Your database is misconfigured: Use UTF-8; Everywhere; Always.

Comment: @Williham: No, sometimes you want UTF-16 :)

Comment: @Williham - UTF-8 takes up MORE space than UTF-16 when the majority of your characters are outside the traditional ASCII set. So yes, sometimes, for some languages, you want UTF-16.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this for an example of allowing only a specific set of characters (whitelisting), which IMO is better and safer:

```
var allowed = /[a-ZA-Z0-9]/; // etc.

window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("test");

    input.onkeypress = function () {
        // Cross-browser
        var evt = arguments[0] || event;
        var char = String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode);

        // Is the key allowed?
        if (!allowed.test(char)) {
            // Cancel the original event
            evt.cancelBubble = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

From:
[prevent typing non ascii characters in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509516/prevent-typing-non-ascii-characters-in-a-textbox)

Alternately you can use regex to strip out non ascii characters.

see here: [How to remove all non - ASCII characters from a string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200594/how-to-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-ruby)

Comment: +1 for good javascript solution. However a check in RoR before inserting into the database will also be required.

Answer (score 1):

You *want* some javascript to tell users when they put such characters in the form. You *need* a validation routine in your RoR code to make sure that only acceptable characters are actually placed in the database.