# iOS 7 - Disable emoji keyboard on UIWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my app I'm using a UIWebView to display a web page. The user can type in some text field, but he should not use emoji cause website can't handle them.

Is there a way to disable emoji keyboard on my UIWebView?

Comment: Does your site lack support for Unicode characters or just the fonts to display Emoji?  The web view keyboard is hard to control (and getting harder with iOS8).  Your best bet is probably input filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can overwrite `UIKeyboardType` or `UIKeyboardAppearance` for a `UIWebView`. You could always filter the user input on the web page using JavaScript. Here's an example of allowing only ASCII (a-z, 0-9) characters on an input field in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509702/220307